# PySimpleGUI, sg.Output inalterable

Tags: python, output, pysimplegui

How I can make the output read-only, without being able to delete or change the text inside it?

```
class TelaLogin:
    def __init__(self):

        layout= [
            [sg.Image(data=bordacima, key='__IMAGE3__')],
            [sg.Image(data=emailimg, pad=(301,0), key='__IMAGE8__')],
            [sg.Input(justification='left', pad=(343, 0), size=(25, 0))],
            [sg.Text('')],
            [sg.Image(data=senhaimg, pad=(301,0), key='__IMAGE7__')],
            [sg.Input(justification='left', password_char=('*'), size=(25, 0), pad=(343, 0))],
            [sg.Button('', image_data=conectar1, button_color=('black', 'black'), pad=(383, 7))],
            ***[sg.Output(size=(40, 4), pad=(281, 4))],***
        ]

        self.janela = sg.Window('UniquePT').layout(layout)
        
        

    def Conectar(self):
        while True:
            self.button, self.values = self.janela.Read()
            print(f'Conectando...')
            GAME = login(self)
            print(f'')
            print(f'')
```

Comment: I am Brazilian, I do not speak English very well, if I was impolite in my question or specified it incorrectly I apologize.
I'm looking for help, if you can't help me everything is fine without any problem.

Comment: My comment wasn't about your English or whether you were being polite — only that your question was off-topic because you appeared to be asking for someone else to do research about what you want to do and then write some code for you showing how to do it. which is off-topic for this website.

Comment: I don't know much about PySimpleGUI,, but from reading the documentation it sounds like you might want to use a [Multiline Element](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/#multiline-element) instead of an [Output  Element](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/#output-element) because the former has both a `disabled` and a `write_only` option but not the latter.

Comment: it's because I don't understand much English, so maybe my specification was misinformed, I apologize.
but that was not quite it, I would never want something easy, I would like to be doing it myself, I posted the code just for a better understanding of who could be helping me, and because I already tried it in several methods and I couldn't.
I’m going to follow these guidelines, like the ones that passed me there now, I believe it will help me a lot.
thank you friend.